Book on Coq that helps me write proofs regarding integral equations
I want to read a book about Coq that would help me construct proofs of theorems in signal processing, particularly Fourier and Wavelet Transforms.
Have seen https://coq.inria.fr/documentation but unsure which book would be most suitable.

That is a mighty specific subject for a book.  I’d instead look for a Coq project which does that.  There might one or there might be none.

How about simpler proofs in mathematics ? Is there any one of them that delves into proving actual mathematical theorems (e.g. series, combinatorics, ...).

I found some related resources regarding doing analysis in Coq: https://perso.crans.org/cohen/CoqWS2018.pdf

Why not look at some research papers on this topic? I think most books serve general purposes. Perhaps you may find these papers helpful: https://inria.hal.science/hal-01728828/file/CICM18.pdf https://css.csail.mit.edu/6.888/2015/papers/jrubin.pdf Nevertheless, formalizing the digital processing algorithms in Coq can be challenging since you have to take care of every single detail. Good luck!

This is a stretch, but Mathematics in Lean covers a lot of mathematical topics in Lean (not Coq).

Unfortunately, Coq is maybe not your tool of choice.
Real analysis in Coq is still work in progress, and not much has been formalized yet. The state of the art, to the best of my knowledge, is MathComp-Analysis. It should already have most of the machinery required to define the Fourier and wavelet transforms, but you'd still have to first develop all the mathematical machinery yourself. If you have a good and rigorous grasp of all the relevant mathematics, you could have a go at it, but I don't expect it to be easy.
Lean is probably somewhat bit better in terms of classical analysis, but I'd expect not too much. I think maybe you should look into Isabelle too.
